# 7 bit LFSR implementation in C#

Tags: c#

I have a 7 bit Linear feedback shift register.

The bits pattern is like this:

D7......D0 bits total 7 bits.

initial bits are 0000001

now using this initial bit pattern the following pattern of bits i should get.

**0**00**0**001 **0**00**0**010 **0**00**0**100 **0**00**1**000 **0**01**0**000 **0**10**0**000 **1**00**0**000 **0**01**0**001    ............

The bits shown in **bold** are X-Ored and then the entire bit pattern is shifted to left by 1.

After corresponding 8 shifting, I need the bits which are in extreme left. In this case the bold bits in the extreme left (D7) **00000010**.
**strong text**

Comment: `D7......D0 bits total 7 bits` - total is 8 bits: `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

Comment: It would be nice if you could try it yourself and tells us what you tried and how that didn't work.

Comment: i tried to load initial bits and i able to X-or the required bits  but i dont know how to shift them to left and collect all the 8 bits of extreme together.

Comment: Shouldn't the next value after **0**00**1**000 be **0**01**0**001? Don't you normally shift in the value of the XOR?

Comment: No because in this case 0 & 1 is X-ored and the result is shifted to one left and the 0 at extreme left will go to extreme right hence next value is 0010000. Its the  7 bit LFSR for bluetooth signals.